# Customize error message when body field is of incorrect type ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this ASP.NET Core Web API controller:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ParamountCactusAPI.Models.Account;
using ParamountCactusAPI.Models.Authentication;
using ParamountCactusAPI.Services.Database;

namespace ParamountCactusAPI.Controllers.v1
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/v1/auth")]
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _databaseContext;

        public AuthenticationController(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _databaseContext = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(AccountRegister registerData)
        {
            List<Account> accounts = _databaseContext.Accounts.ToList();

            Account account = new Account
            {
                Id = accounts.Count + 1,
                FirstName = registerData.FirstName,
                LastName = registerData.LastName,
                Email = registerData.Email,
                Password = registerData.Password
            };

            _databaseContext.Accounts.Add(account);
            _databaseContext.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(account);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `AccountRegister` class:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ParamountCactusAPI.Models.Authentication
{
    public class AccountRegister
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "FirstName must be between 1 and 50 characters long")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "LastName must be between 1 and 50 characters long")]
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

When I send an integer as LastName, I get the following response

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-c7c9b99e3d5455298a650e2a7d7b1511-4634cde88d3cb185-00",
  "errors": {
    "registerData": [
      "The registerData field is required."
    ],
    "$.lastName": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.lastName | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 15."
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't want this

```
    "registerData": [
      "The registerData field is required."
    ],
    "$.lastName": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.lastName | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 15."
    ]
```

to be the response error because it mentions `registerData` which is an internal variable name and includes technical details, so I would instead send a custom type error instead of the above.

I am sending the data using Swagger

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of action filter attribute to custom the message shown. Model Validation/Binding won’t work since it is not called if the json is incorrect.

> 1.Edit your custom  action filter attribute.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ValidateResultAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("result executing called");
            if (!filterContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var modelState = filterContext.ModelState;
                Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                var fields = modelState.Keys.ToList();

                foreach (var item in fields)
                {
                   //Hide or display the property
                    keyValuePairs.Add(item.ToString(), item.ToString() + ": Custom error message");
                }

                var errorResponse = new ValidationErrorResponse(keyValuePairs);
                filterContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorResponse);
            }
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

> 2.Edit the custom ErrorResponse

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class ValidationErrorResponse
    {
        //Custom message as you wish
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string?> Errors { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeCustom { get; set; }

        public ValidationErrorResponse(Dictionary<string, string> customDetails)
        {
            //Here to edit how you display the property
            DateTimeCustom = DateTime.Now;
            Message = "Validation Failed";
            Errors = customDetails.ToDictionary(
                kvp => kvp.Key,
                kvp => kvp.Value?.ToString()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

> 3.Add the attribute in your controller or action

```
[ValidateResult]
[ApiController]
[Route("/v1/auth")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(Account registerData)
    {
         …
    }
}
```

> 4.Test

[image]
[image]